# Replace Words on the basis of Bigram Frequency,Python

Tags: python, return-value, levenshtein-distance, function, n-gram

I have a series type object where i have to apply a function that uses bigrams to correct the word in case it occurs with another one. I created a bigrams list , sorted it according to frequency (highest comes first) and called it fdist .

```
bigrams = [b for l in text2 for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
freq = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams) #computes freq of occurrence
fdist = freq.keys() # sorted according to freq
```

Next ,I created a function that accepts each line ("or sentence","object of a list") and uses the bigram to decide whether to correct it further or not.

```
def bigram_corr(line): #function with input line(sentence)
    words = line.split() #split line into words
    for word1, word2 in zip(words[:-1], words[1:]): #generate 2 words at a time words 1,2 followed by 2,3 3,4 and so on
        for i,j in fdist: #iterate over bigrams
            if (word2==j) and (jf.levenshtein_distance(word1,i) < 3): #if 2nd words of both match, and 1st word is at an edit distance of 2 or 1, replace word with highest occurring bigram
               word1=i #replace
               return word1 #return word
```

The problem is that only a single word is returned for an entire sentence , eg :
"Lts go twards the east is" replaced by lets . It looks that further iterations arent working.
The for loop for word1, word2 works this way :
"Lts go" in 1st iteration, which will be eventually replaced by "lets" as lets occurs more frequently with "go"

"go towards" in 2nd iteration.

"towards the" in 3rd iteration.. and so on.

There is a minor error which i cant figure out , please help.

Comment: Please clarify. What is the expected result of `bigram_corr("Lets go towards the east is")`?

Comment: edited it, please check . i need the entire sentence to be returned .

Comment: You're returning prematurely.

Comment: Readers may be interested in the chat discussion that led to the creation of this post. There may be additional clues there. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14784810#14784810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing `word1 = i` with the expectation that this will modify the contents of `words`. But this won't happen. If you want to modify `words`, you'll have to do so directly. Use `enumerate` to keep track of `word1`'s index.

As 2rs2ts pointed out, you're returning early. If you want the inner loop to terminate once you find the first good replacement, `break` instead of returning. Then return at the end of the function.

```
def bigram_corr(line): #function with input line(sentence)
    words = line.split() #split line into words
    for idx, (word1, word2) in enumerate(zip(words[:-1], words[1:])):
        for i,j in fdist: #iterate over bigrams
            if (word2==j) and (jf.levenshtein_distance(word1,i) < 3): #if 2nd words of both match, and 1st word is at an edit distance of 2 or 1, replace word with highest occurring bigram
                words[idx] = i
                break
    return " ".join(words)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this may be closer to what OP was trying to accomplish than what I offered, based on `word1=i`.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement halts the function entirely. I think what you want is:

```
def bigram_corr(line):
    words = line.split()
    words_to_return = []
    for word1, word2 in zip(words[:-1], words[1:]):
        for i,j in fdist:
            if (word2==j) and (jf.levenshtein_distance(word1,i) < 3):
               words_to_return.append(i)
    return ' '.join(words_to_return)
```

This puts each of the words which you have processed into a list, then rejoins them with spaces and returns that entire string, since you said something about returning "the entire sentence."

I am not sure if the semantics of your code are correct, since I don't have the `jf` library or whatever it is that you're using and therefore I can't test this code, so this may or may not solve your problem entirely. But this will help.

Comment: words_to_return = [] should come after 1 st for loop, right? coz it will get bigger and bigger with multiple sentences..

Comment: @Sword What were you expecting to pass in as `line`? I assumed it would be a string of text ending with a newline (`'\n'`). But no, this is the correct place to put `words_to_return`.

Comment: yes true.. i initialized it after the loop and got an error.i've executed it now..lets see..

Comment: it did not work , but you taught me a new logic.. thanks bro :)

Comment: @Sword right. I figured after seeing Kevin's answer that you were trying to do something other than what I showed you. But I'm glad you picked something up from this.